# Accessing NSData bytes - Not the same value on debugger

Tags: objective-c, console, byte, nsdata

I'm facing a problem that I don't understand. Before beginning to explain it, even if I have worked on a Swift project this year that was using some Objective-C, I am new to this language and its concepts.

So, there is my problem : I want to access the bytes of an NSData object. I know there several ways to do so :

```
[data bytes]; 

data.bytes;

[data getBytes: dest, length: [data length]];
```

But each method doesn't return the same value as the console, when I'm using `po [data bytes]`.

Can you explain me why this happens ? I don't really understand what I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` and `data.bytes` are of two totally different types. `data` is an instance of `NSData`, while `data.bytes` is a raw pointer (`const void *`). When you call `po` in the debugger (short for "print object"), it will call `-description` on things which inherit from `NSObject`, or just print the value if they do not.

In this case, since `data` is an `NSData` (which has `-description`), if you `po data`, it calls `[data description]` and prints the result of that out; since `NSData` knows how to nicely format its contents, it will print nicely.

However, since `data.bytes` is a `void *`, there is no way for the debugger to know how to print it (`void *` can point to anything; how to interpret it is totally up to you) so it just prints out the pointer itself.

If you want to print the data from the debugger directly, you can tell it how to interpret the pointer and print it out. If you know that the data blob is `n` bytes long, you can run the following command:

```
p/x *(uint8_t (*)[<n>])data.bytes
```

where `<n>` is replaced with the literal length of the data (e.g. `uint8_t (*)[8])`). `*(uint8_t (*)[<n>])data.bytes` tells the debugger to reinterpret `data.bytes` as an array of `n` bytes (giving it the length so it knows how much data to read from memory) while `p/x` tells it to print the hex values of the bytes it finds.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's pretty much clearer now. But, when I use the command `po [data bytes]`in console, it prints something like 0x14ee2ee8, let's say.

And when I use the command `po bytes`, where bytes is the result of [data bytes], it prints something like "3w\x80\x88\x17  ".

What is exactly the value returned by `po [data bytes] ` ?

Comment: When you store `[data bytes]` in a variable `bytes`, what is the type of `bytes`? What does your declaration look like?

Comment: `bytes` is a `const char*`.

Comment: Ah — there's a difference there. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410616-bytes?language=objc), you'll see that the return type of `[data bytes]` is `const void *`. A `void *` in C and Objective-C means "this can point to anything and if you want to actually use this pointer, you'll have to cast it to a type you know". When you print out a `void *` in the debugger, it has no way of knowing how to interpret it, so it prints the pointer. A `const char *` however, is a type it knows how to do something with, so it prints it like a string.

Comment: In the debugger, `char *`'s will always be interpreted and printed as strings (annoyingly, sometimes), unless you tell the debugger otherwise. Your best best is actually to refer to the `bytes` as `const uint8_t *`. This will also print more nicely.

Comment: The edit in your answer has unblocked me! Now I am sure I get the correct data. And I think that if I cast the `[data bytes]` to an array of `uint8_t`, I will be able to work with it, right ? Like, accessing each byte in this array ?

Comment: Correct, that is the right way to work with the bytes directly; accessing the pointer via `const uint8_t *` will allow you to access it byte-by-byte.

Comment: @VincentAunai Happy to have helped. :)